# how to open custom drop-down upwards

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, twitter-bootstrap-2

Currently, I'm working on a custom AngularJS drop-down, which is represented by the HTML structure below:

```
<div>
  <label></label>
  <div>
    <a ng-class="{active: popover}">
      <div></div> <!-- the selected item -->
    </a>
    <div style="position: relative;">  <!-- THIS is the div that presents -->
                                       <!-- the list with the menu items-->
      <div class="popover" ng-class="{popover-show}">
        <input /> <--! this is a search box -->
        <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The rules for .popover and .popover-show are from Twitter Bootstrap but the have the additional rules below:

```
.popover{
  top: 20px;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  max-width: none;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
.popover.popover-show {
    display : block !important;
}
```

The div with the `postition:relative` is the one that is wrap
The directive seems to work  fine. However, when it's positioned below the middle of the page and it has too many items so it exceeds the window's height by default the vertical scroll of the bar appears. I've been looking to other similar questions, but none of them was close enough to my case. So, my question is what would be the smartest way to detect when I am about to exceed the window height (and of course, the best place to do it - CSS, the directive) and to set the bottom to 0?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I'm trying to get around without using jQuery and the JS files for Twitter Bootstrap

Comment: You could set `bottom:` instead of `top:` on your popover.  Though that's just as likely to overflow above the viewport as it currently overflows below...

Comment: Yes, but I mean how to check if I'm going to exceed the window height.

Answer (score 0):

use the data-placement=" "  identifier

this is how to do it for a popover:

HTML 
`<a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Content">Click</a>`

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});
</script>
```

For dropdowns this will work, to change from dropping down to dropping up,
HTML

```
<div class="dropup">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to repalce the w3 source before you incite a flame-war.

Comment: I guess I didn't consider that may be frowned upon, regardless, I think that answers the question.

Comment: I'm actually trying to get around using jQuery and the bootstrap js part. I seems good idea to update the question

Comment: If your just trying to use a bootstrap dropdown, without the jQuery popover effect, then the code at the bottom of my answer should work. if you replace the class with "dropup" (or "dropdown") it should do that as well.  I don't really use angular so there could be another issue I'm not seeing.  But I know what you're talking about, when the length of the drop down exceeds the length of the page visible it moves up instead.  I'm not sure where that is defined in Bootstrap, but It could probabyl be found with inspect element.

Comment: @JackGraham I'm only speaking from experience. I've had seemingly innocent answers downvoted to oblivion because of it.